# Pexpect - login to Cisco device, grab just the hostname from the config.

Tags: python, expect, cisco

I am running a python script that uses pexpect to send commands to a cisco device. In the process I need to get the device's hostname. I have the IP, but need the hostname. There are two ways to retrieve it; first, it comes up at the prompt prior to the # symbol (ie DEVICE-01#) or via a command like "Show run hostname" which outputs "hostname DEVICE-01".

I could pull the entire config into a file and parse it using ciscoconfparse but that seems a bit heavy. What method can I use to get just the hostname?

Once I've logged in, I've tried:

```
c = pexpect.spawn('connection stuff')
#login happening here
c.expect('#')
c.sendline('show run hostname')
hostname = c.before 
#use hostname for use in later commands
etc etc
```

This c.before statement doesn't give me what I'm looking for. I think it is a timing thing on when I use it but that won't work for the amount of devices I will need to connect to.

Ideas on a good method?

Thanks!

Comment: Put another c.expect('#') after the send line then print c.before.  I'm fairly sure c.before prints what it had before the last expect was found.  In your case, what was shown before your c.expect('#') line. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Yeah. I just figured that out but it seems that now it is giving me the hostname with a carriage return or something previous to it. So when I print it out it looks like
<space here>
DEVICE-01

Comment: That sounds like it can be easily remedied by trimming the first couple characters off the string ( string[-1:] ) or by using the replace method ( string.replace("\n", "") )

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got it sorted out. Was using :

```
c = pexpect.spawn('connection stuff')
#login happening here
c.expect('#')
hostname = c.before 
print "Connected to " + hostname
```

But that would break the script for some reason. So I added a new line prior to the expect to get a new prompt:

```
c = pexpect.spawn('connection stuff')
#login happening here
c.expect('#')
c.sendline('\n')
c.expect('#')
hostname = c.before 
print "Connected to " + hostname
```

which gave me this:

```
Connected to 
DEVICE01
```

Then I figured I could find a way to remove that new line again:

```
c = pexpect.spawn('connection stuff')
#login happening here
c.expect('#')
c.sendline('\n')
c.expect('#')
h = c.before 
hostname = h.lstrip()
print "Connected to " + hostname
```

Which resulted in:

```
Connected to DEVICE-01
```

what I wanted.